# Proxy in node.js Modules

Tags: javascript

I would like to set up 2 node.js scripts that act as a proxy together

1st script allows you to request pages

2nd script receives requests, querying content on a connection

If there is project providing the same fictionality could you post the link.

If not modules which modules would be helpful in accomplishing the task?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a very vague as it does not appear you require a proxy at all. If you wish to monitor your application, the one serving up your pages, you could give [hummingbird](http://hummingbirdstats.com/) a try. If you do actually require a proxy server then I would recommend [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) from the nodejitsu guys.

Alternatively you can set up a single server which routes your view files and "queries content". If you add a more detailed description of your requirements you may get a more helpful answer.